# Accessing associated fields in merged scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by, scopes

Model:
A vehicle has_many mileage readings entered (in this particular case, a vehicle is running on an hour meter).

In the view I need to display the largest hour reading entered for each vehicle. This includes displaying several fields about the vehicle from the vehicle model and only the largest related hours reading from the mileage model.

The problem I having is around merging the 2 scopes:

```
scope :max_hours, Mileage.maximum(:hours, :group => :vehicle_id)
```

and

```
scope :max_vehicle_hours; lambda { joins(:vehicle).merge(Mileage.max_hours) }
```

I can only access information in the view from the Vehicle model, and don't know how to access the result of the max_hours scope.
Controller:

```
@vehicle = Vehicle.max_vehicle_hours
```

using `<% @vehicle.each do |m| %>` I have tried:

```
m.mileage.hours
m.max_hours.mileage
```

but just can't work it out. (the error is undefined method `mileage' for #)

Can anyone see what I'm messing up or if theres a better way to do this. many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like I was making this far more complicated than necessary.

```
m.mileages.maximum(:mileage)
```